# SharePoint Online - Move Site and subsites into another site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a site called PROFILES that is one level down from the home site. This site contains about 40 subsites.

I want to move the site and its 40 subsites into another site called RESOURCING which sits at the same level as PROFILES.

I know I can save a site as a template and move it that way, but how can I get all 40 subsites included in that template?

Thanks.

Comment: It works with SharePoint Online. I can get to the site manager for the site collection > site I want to move but it seems that I can't move a sub-site to another site collection from companysite.sharepoint.com to companysite-my.sharepoint.com. I'm trying not to make someone, who created a project sub site under their mysite site, delete it and build it all over again. Blah.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

My suggestion is that you utilize the site manager.

If you visit "http://yoursite/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx", you'll see a site manager, where you can do a move operation of all pages.

1) Select the parent site of the subsite you want to move in the left navigation pane.

2) Check the box next to the subsite you want to move in the right pane.

3) Click **Actions** drop-down and click **Move**.

4) Select Destination of the subsite selected in the next dialog.

Comment: Thanks. Managed to get this working. Had to turn on publishing at Site and Site Collection level first though.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion to use this link: "http://yoursite/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx", as all other searches for moving subsite in sharepoint did not show up this result. I also use sharepoint online, appears to be the foundation version, and get the "File not found" error. I'm hoping that there is a way to do this, without resorting to programming (we are not programmers) or expensive tools that are available. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Sitemanager in SP2013 tells me "It is not possible to move or copy one element..." so i cannot move/copy the entire site.

Comment: I see the sitemanager but get the "Sorry something went wrong error". This is with SharePoint online. Anyone manage to get around this?

Comment: Jacques - this was applicable to SP 2010 and SP Online (at the time of the post), but as per my understanding, this is still available with SharePoint Online. Are you using this against a specific site collection? User41334, above, indicated he was experiencing a similar issue, against SharePoint Online.

Comment: @QuinnJohns Do you know if this can be utilized to migrate a site (Site A) to become a subsite of a different site (Site B)?

Comment: I apologize -- it's been a while. I'll defer to the community. Per my recollection, you could do that between sites, but, for server to server you would do backup/restore.

Answer (score 2):

We've purchased [Sharegate](https://en.share-gate.com/) to handle our site moves & migration needs because it wraps all the necessary Powershell scripts into a single GUI app. Since business requirements change periodically I found myself moving sites/lists/libraries more often than I'd prefer.

[SharePoint Maven](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-move-sites-in-sharepoint/) also has a couple options spelled out with pros and cons for each.

Answer (score 0):

With sharepoint online this does not seem to be possible. Using powershell even the export command is not avaialble.
Using the Site Manager yields "File not found"

Comment: I am able to do this in SharePoint Online using the sitemanager.aspx page Quinn's answer discusses. Maybe it was added to SharePoint Online after your answer.