# move subsites from one site collection to another in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a couple of subsites under one site collection to be moved to another. I am new to this so please explain the steps.

Comment: I would suggest investing in a migration tool for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way of migration is to use any Migration Tool.
I would recommend, [**Saketa Migrator**](https://saketa.com/migrator/). 
All you have to do is register for a trial version which would be of 7 days(which I guess is quite enough if you know how to manage :P) and download the app.
Just paste you source and destination and click the play button. Its quite easy.

You also can migrate manually by saving the site as template and providing the downloaded template in the destination site collection.

Answer (score 2):

For such activities, better you should use tools and as of now there are two most popular and accurate tools are available in market, one is as Tushar said [Saketa Migrator](https://saketa.com/migrator/) and second is [Sharegate](https://en.share-gate.com/). Both the tools are available for trial version and security is also considered very well.

Answer (score 1):

One of the methods is to save the first SharePoint online Site as a template and use it in the new account. After that copy and move the content between these sites by mapping the site to a network location. Another option is to try third party migration tool.

- Save the source site as a template
- Attach the saved template to the destination site
- Copy the content from source site to the destination site

You may also get help from below links:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_cloud/2012/03/11/migrating-content-between-sharepoint-online-site-collections/

http://sharepoint-content-migration.blogspot.in/2016/01/move-sharepoint-online-site-content-to.html

Comment: Please add some detail along with posting just link. Because it will be of no use once the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Open a Site that you need to Save as Template and Navigate to Site Settings ->Under “Site Actions”  select “Save Site as Template”.
Note: If yours is a publishing site it won't show you an option to save site as template.  To get it working follow link below 
 [here](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/05/03/missing-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sharegate for migration. its a third party tool and it provides the 15 days trial period. however, in the trial version, it migrates the random content from sites but if you have less data than it works fine or later you can move content manually by saving list and libraries as the template.

Answer (score -1):

You can move sub-sites from one site collection to another site collection by navigating to url `https://<yoursite>/layouts/sitemanager.aspx` .

1. After navigating to this page select the sub-sites you want to move to another site collection.
2. In Action Menu you have sub-menu as Move.

For more reference you can refer [SharePoint Online - Move Site and sub-sites into another site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54522/sharepoint-online-move-site-and-subsites-into-another-site)
Through this you can move your sites to new Site Collection.

Let me know if it helped you .

Comment: this is equivalent to going to site setting -> content and structure. but it only allows me to move sites in the same site collection. I am not seeing the other site collections.