# Moving a subsite

Tags: sub-site

So I have a subsite titled "Quality." I want to move another subsite underneath the Quality subsite. Is this possible? I'm in the Content and Structure view, but the "move" section (under Actions)is grayed out. This is all new to me! Help!

Comment: Came across this, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/54547/50162, not sure if you are using online or on-prem but this might get you moving in the right place.

Comment: I'm using SP online with Office 365

Comment: I am using the same technology. I just got it to work. If you go to the following: https://<SITE>.sharepoint.com/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx. This will bring up the Site Manager and you can then move subsites around.

Comment: thanks IEMaster, I think now that it's a "permission" issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get around the permission issue, you can try saving the site as a template and then creating a new site from this template. If you select to save with the "include content" option selected you will bring all data with the template.