# Is it possible to convert an existing Team SharePoint into a Subsite within a Communication SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sub-site, team-sites, communication-site

The company I work for, recently, created a Communication SharePoint and has asked everyone to create subsites within this SharePoint. I have already been working with a Team SharePoint with my own team and would like to avoid moving or creating another SharePoint seeing that my existing SharePoint works perfectly well for my team.

So I would like to know, is it possible to connect or convert a existing Team SharePoint into a Subsite within a Communication SharePoint? If this is possible, can someone please explain how to do so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is SharePoint Online, the only was is to migrate the data using a third party tool like Sharegate.

Depending on the reasoning for this request, I would push back and direct requester to Microsoft guidance on modern site structure, where by avoid the use of subsite and using hub sites to easily navigate. This simplifies management and enables greater user experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the entire team site to the new location, consider using **third-party tools** to do the trick ([Sharegate](https://sharegate.com/products/sharegate-desktop/migration), for example) so that you can keep all the contents and apps along.

If you only need the site contents in the team site, you can also use **Content and Structure** page (`_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx`) to move lists, libraries, pages, etc.

Here is a similar post for your reference: 
[SharePoint Online - Move Site and subsites into another site.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54522/sharepoint-online-move-site-and-subsites-into-another-site)

Comment: _layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx no longer exists in SharePoint Online

Comment: @WarwickW Yes, not from UI, but site collection administrators can still enter this page via this URL.

Comment: ah no they can't, the page has been removed from the system

Comment: @WarwickWW well it is available for me. It is not a good solution though, so nevermind.